# How to make array.push() a string multiplied by i

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have been looking for a while for this answer and most results bring up people NOT wanting to push more than once, and its hard to find a straight forward solution / alternative.

I have been tasked with a exercise to output a tower in an array. It increments based on its floor size. For example.

```
[
  '  *  ', 
  ' *** ', 
  '*****'
]
```

I am still leaning the ropes of Javascript and I am intrigued to learn, here is what I have come up with:

```
function towerBuilder(floors) {
  let arr = [];
  let space = " ";
  let tower = "*"  

  for (i = 0; i < floors; i++) {
    arr.push(space, tower * i, space);
  }
    console.log(arr)
}

towerBuilder(3);
```

console.log shows (Array [ 0, NaN, 0, 0, NaN, 0, 0, NaN, 0 ]) - I guess multiplying a string is a bad idea.

I could probably create multiple for loops and have each push in its own loop, but that would look really messy.

Is there a way to push spaces and *'s multiplied by the for loop?

Thanks

Comment: you can't multiply strings, but you can use [`.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

Comment: const totalNumberofRows = 5;
let output="";
    for (let i = 1; i <= totalNumberofRows; i++) {
        for (let j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            output+=j + "     ";
        }
        console.log(output);
        output="";
    }

Comment: You need to get the length of the spaces to surround and the character to stuff in there so `function towerBuilder(floors) {
  let arr = [];
  let space = " ";
  let tower = "*";
  let b = floors + 1;
  while (--b) {
    let sx = space.repeat(floors - (b));
    let tx = tower.repeat(b);
    let x = sx + tx + sx;
    arr.push(x);
  }
  return arr;
}

let t = towerBuilder(3);`
alert(t);

Comment: This is not truly a duplicate of the marked question given the desired output, voting to re-open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 function towerBuilder(floors) {
      let arr = [];
      let tower = '*';
      let space = ' ';
      let total = (2 * floors) + 1;
      for (i = 0; i < floors; i++) {
        let count = (2 * i) + 1;
        let free = (total - count) / 2;
                     arr.push(`${space.repeat(free-1)}${tower.repeat(count)}${space.repeat(free-1)}`);
      }
      console.log(arr)
    }

    towerBuilder(3);
```

Comment: this does not put spaces in the strings as the example desired output shows

Comment: Question was modified after answer was submitted. Answer corrected. Please undo downvote.

Comment: I was able to fix this without any issues so I still consider this the answer.

Comment: After the answer edit it produces the defined output. I would suggest `i = 0;` instead be `let i = 0;` to avoid a global however.  I still consider the question to not be a duplicate of the marked one in the close note but only "related"